# Facebook, embedding user wall to application

Tags: facebook, fbml

I need to write application (in PHP/JavaScript) like http://www.facebook.com/johnmayer?v=app_178091127385. Embedding player is not difficult for me but I don't have any idea how to embed user wall in application - wall in this application is the same as on user wall.

Comment: what do you mean by user wall? there are different objects on user wall. Do you want to get all posts from user?

Comment: By user wall I mean http://www.facebook.com/johnmayer?v=wall. As you can see posts on this page are the same (and look almost the same) as on http://www.facebook.com/johnmayer?v=app_178091127385 below the player. I need to do the same.